# Custom Admin form doesnt load layout file

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am developing a new module for Magento 2.1, the admin form for adding new entries doesnt load the correct layout. The layout that is loaded is as follows:
[image]

My Folder structure is as follows:
[image]

I have a NewAction.php in the Controller/Adminhtml/Post/NewAction.php:

```
<?php

 namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;

 use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
 use Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Post as Post;

class NewAction extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
/**
 * Edit A Manufacturer Page
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page|\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 */
public function execute()
{
    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();

    $postData = $this->getRequest()->getParam('posts');

    if(is_array($postData)) {

        $post = $this->_objectManager->create(Post::class);

        $post->setData($postData)->save();

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index');
    }
}
}
```

The layout files for post_newaction.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <update handle="posts_test_edit"/>
 <body/>
</page>
```

Also the layout posts_edit.xml file which loads my form(mageplaza_posts_form):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<update handle="styles"/>
<update handle="editor"/>
  <body>
      <referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="mageplaza_posts_form"/>
     </referenceContainer>
 </body>
```

I am completely stuck and out of ideas.

Comment: try this way https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301930/how-to-create-a-block-layout-and-template-for-backend-module-in-magento-2/301940#301940

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to change the name of post_newaction.xml to mageplaza_helloworld_post_new.xml.

You'll also want to change this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <update handle="posts_test_edit"/>
 <body/>
</page>
```

To this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <update handle="posts_edit"/>
 <body/>
</page>
```

I just struggled with this myself for the last 3 hours.