# How to create a Block, Layout and Template for backend module in magento 2

Tags: module, layout, blocks, template, magento2.3.3

I have doubt as how to create Backend Module using block,layout and templates.
After creating the block,I have assigned the block in **app_appdashboard_index.xml** file and I called the block page function in Template file(**appdashboard.phtml**). I didn't get the data from the Block function. It also makes my page empty

Please find the below code for creating Backend module

**File path:app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/Adminhtml/layout/app_appdashboard_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>
            My App
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Dashboard" template="VendorName_ModuleName::appdashboard.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**File path:app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Dashboard.php**

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml;
class Dashboard extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function sayHello()
    {
        return __('Hello World');
    }
}
```

**File path:app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/Adminhtml/templates/appdashboard.phtml**

```
<?php
echo $block->sayHello();
?>
```

Help me as how to get data from block function to template phtml file

Thanks in Advance :)

Regards,

Hari

Comment: Have you created the controller as well?

Answer (score 4):

First you have to craete admin Route file

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml**

***routes.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="[route_name]" frontName="[route_name]">
            <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Now you have to create Controller file which control your route

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/AppDashboard**

**index.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\AppDashboard;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    private $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create(); // this crete an empty page 
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Page Created'));//this is your page heading 
        return $resultPage;// this show page
    }
}
```

Now we are create an Block file

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml**

***Dashboard.php***

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml;

class Dashboard extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function sayHello()
    {
        $txt = 'Hello World';
        return $txt;
    }
}
```

Now Create a phtml file

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/templates**

***appdashboard.phtml***

```
<h1>hello I am From phtml file<?php echo $block->sayHello(); ?></h1>
```

Now filanlly create a Layout file

layout file name must be as this formate and all latters are in lower case.

**[admin_route_name]*[admin_controller_name]*[Controller_filename].xml**

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/layout**

***[admin_route_name]_appdashboard_index.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="VendorName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Dashboard" template="VendorName_ModuleName::appdashboard.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Craete an Menu for acceess this layout

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml**

***menu.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>


 <add id="VendorName_ModuleName::content_elements" title="Pages Menu" module="VendorName_ModuleName" sortOrder="20"  resource="VendorName_ModuleName::content_elements" />

 <add id="VendorName_ModuleName::showpage" title="show Page" module="VendorName_ModuleName" sortOrder="40" parent="VendorName_ModuleName::content_elements" action="[admin_route_name]/appdashboard/index" resource="VendorName_ModuleName::showpage"/>

    </menu>
</config>
```

Now run Cammand in Terminal

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento c:f
php bin/magento c:c
```

***I Hope This helps you***

Comment: I think we have to replace **Adminhtml** by **adminhtml** in app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/`Adminhtml`/layout or templates

Comment: @urbansurfers  Thanks for your suggestion. I updated my post.