# Magento 2 admin menu action result Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page. on click

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, action, adminmenu

I have succesfully added a new admin menu. But the problem is whenever i clicked the admin menu button, I got Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page.

Here're some of my codes.

[image]

This is my menu.xml

```
     <add id="Testing_Basic::menu_item" title="Manage Items" module="Testing_Basic" sortOrder="10" parent="Testing_Basic::menu" action="Webpage/Create/Index" resource="Testing_Basic::menu_item"/>
```

And this is my directories looks like.

[image]

[image]

This is my

> Controller/Adminhtml/Webpage/Index.php

```
<?php
/**
* Webkul Grid Controller
*
* @category    Webkul
* @package     Webkul_Grid
* @author      Webkul Software Private Limited
*
*/
namespace Testing\Basic\Controller\Adminhtml\Webpage;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
 */
protected $_resultPageFactory;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context        $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
}

/**
 * Grid List page.
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
 */
public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Testing_Basic::grid_list');
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Grid List'));

    return $resultPage;
}

/**
 * Check Grid List Permission.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Testing_Basic::grid_list');
    }
  }
```

And this is my routes.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
    * Webkul_Grid route xml
    *
    * @category    Webkul
    * @package     Webkul_Grid
    * @author      Webkul Software Private Limited
    *
    */
    -->
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
     <router id="admin">
       <route id="create" frontName="create">
       <module name="Testing_Basic" />
       </route>
       </router>
    </config>
```

Comment: Answer is here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301930/how-to-create-a-block-layout-and-template-for-backend-module-in-magento-2/301940#301940

Comment: Please add your index controller and routes.xml file code also.

Comment: @Msquare thanks. I tried following your tutorial but I stuck in blank page. There's no side menu whenever I clicked the button.

Comment: @KishorThummar added my routes and index controller

Comment: Show your error here

Comment: Please follow full tutorial of my answer and then let me inform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add code in menu.xml

```
 <add 
    id="Testing_Basic::item" 
    title="Manage Items" 
    module="Testing_Basic" 
    sortOrder="10" 
    parent="Testing_Basic::menu" 
    action="create/webpage/index" 
    resource="Testing_Basic::item"
    />
```

etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="create" frontName="create">
            <module name="Testing_Basic" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

and controler file path like

/Controller/Adminhtml/Webpage/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Testing\Basic\Controller\Adminhtml\Webpage;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface as HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
class Index extends Action implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Index action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Testing_Basic::item');
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Grid List'), __('Grid List'));
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Manage Grid'), __('Manage Grid'));
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Grid List'));

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

hope this help you. :)

Comment: Thanks its finally not showing the error. Just realize that I put "s" in my controller. But I must be missing something because the button is redirecting to blank page now.

Comment: added my index controller code..

Comment: thanks. It's finally showing up. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

It might help someone, Today, I faced the same issue **Magento ver. 2.3.5** none of the above methods works for me:
Then I checked the module controller and found this  code :

```
 /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Mymodule_Test::Test');
    }
```

Solution: Update Users Role from admin and it will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in Magento 2.4.0. The reason was because the module folder was not correctly named. For example: the name should have been DemoModule and the incorrect name was ModuleDemo.